# Montar uma matriz em RGB que seja equivalente a uma GrayScale com uma cor alterada

Tags: matlab

Tenho uma matriz em Matlab de uma dimensão ou seja grayscale, só que gostaria de criar uma equivalente em RGB no qual todo preto desta, i.e. todo zero seja um tom de verde. E que todas as outras cores branco e cinza sejam mantidas da matriz original na mesma cor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você não informou a matriz original, vou supor essa:

```
% matriz original:
matrix_cinza = rand(64, 64);
```

E visualizando:

```
% imagem original
% Sendo: cat(3, VERMELHO, VERDE, AZUL)
% Mas, como é escala de cinza os três canais são iguais.
imagem_cinza = cat(3, matrix_cinza, matrix_cinza, matrix_cinza);
```

[image: Imagem Orignal]

Para destacar os elementos pretos você pode criar uma `matriz_destaca` e mudar o valor dos que forem preto para 1. Nesse caso, foi considerado preto os valores menores que 0.1, mas você pode alterar para o nível desejado em `matrix_destaca < 0.1`.

```
 matrix_destaca = matrix_cinza;
 matrix_destaca(matrix_destaca < 0.1) = 1;
```

Então, você pode gerar a imagem destacado apenas a camada verde imagem:

```
 imagem_destacada = cat(3, matrix_cinza, matrix_destaca, matrix_cinza);
 image(imagem_destacada);
```

O que resulta em:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]